# Overestimating a function involving square roots

Tags: inequality

Plotting the function $$f(a,b)=1+a+b-\sqrt{(1+a+b)^2-4a},$$ it's clear that for all $a,b>0$, $f(a,b)\in(0,2)$.

It's easy to prove that $f(a,b)>0$ but I'm struggling to show $f(a,b)<2$ via a sequence of inequalities. I'm sure it's easy enough to take a calculus approach to prove it, but can anyone see a sequence of inequalities that would do the job instead?

Answer (score 1):

You want $$
f(a,b)=1+a+b-\sqrt{(1+a+b)^2-4a} < 2
$$
or 
 $$
 (1+a+b)^2-4a > (1+a+b - 2)^2  = (1+a+b)^2  - 4 (1+a+b) + 4
$$
or

$$
 0 >   - 4 (1+b) + 4
$$
or $b>0$ which is given.

Extra remark: there is going to be no problem with the root. As $b>0$, we have $(1+a+b)^2-4a > (1+a)^2-4a = (1-a)^2 \ge 0$.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful.

Comment: If you like the answer please accept it, i.e. click on the tick.  Thank you, Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Your inequality is equivalent to $$a+b-1<\sqrt{(1+a+b)^2-4a}$$
and square this inequality.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Trick: $(1+a + b)^2 - 4a >$

$[1 + (a+b)]^2 - 4(a+b) =$

$1 + 2(a+b) + (a+b)^2 -4(a+b)=$

$1 - 2(a+b) + (a+b)^2 =$

$((a+b) - 1)^2$

So $f(a,b) = 1+a+b-\sqrt{(1+a+b)^2-4a}$

$ < 1+a+b - \sqrt{(a+b -1)^2}$

$ = 1 + a + b - |a+b -1|$

If $a+b > 1$ then $f(a,b) < 2$.

If $a+b < 1$ then $f(a,b) < (1+a+b) - (1-(a+b))= 2(a+b) < 2$.

..... or old answer.....

Hint:  $1+a+b-\sqrt{(1+a+b)^2-4a}< 2 \iff \sqrt{(1+a+b)^2 - 4a} > a+b -1$

If $a+b -1 < 0$ that this clear as square roots are never negative[1].

If $a + b - 1 \ge 0$ then

$\sqrt{(1+a+b)^2 - 4a} > a+b -1 \iff (1+a+b)^2 -4a > (a+b-1)^2$

That's easy enough to compare:  $(1+a+b)^2 = 1 + 2(a+b) + (a+b)^2$

And $(a+b-1)^2 = 1 -2(a+b) + (a+b)^2$.

So $(1+a+b)^2 -4a > (a+b-1)^2 \iff 4(a+b) > 4a$.

Which as $b > 0$ that is always true.

===

[1] You do however have to prove $\sqrt{(1+a+b)^2 - 4a}$ always exist.

That is that $(1+a+b)^2 - 4a > 0$

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful.